# Manually re-create the UIImagePicker allowsEditing property

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Within the UIImagePicker class, there is a property allowsEditing, which will take you to a view where you can move/resize and finally crop an image to a specific area.

The view looks like this: [image]

I need to recreate this view manually.  Would there be any existing solutions out there?  Otherwise, any help would be appreciated!

For now, what I've done is to create a single View application in which I have a zoomable UIScrollView.  So at this point, I'm able to move/zoom into a UIImageView that is a subview of the scrollview.  However, I'm not sure how I can show a bounding rectangle on the view and be able to only extract the image within that rectangle.

Thank you!